# How to manage multiple schema maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

this is the first time that I'm using maven-jaxb2-plugin and I'm becoming crazy with this trouble.
I have two .xsd schema from which i get two java packages.

This is my maven-jaxb2-plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>schema1-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <user.language>en</user.language>
                            <user.region>GB</user.region>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/myPath/schema</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>schema1.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>it.mycompany.jaxb1</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
                        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>schema2-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <user.language>en</user.language>
                            <user.region>GB</user.region>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/myPath/schema</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>schema2.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>it.mycompany.jaxb2</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc12</generateDirectory>
                        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When i run mvn complie i get two new folder

```
target/generated-sources/xjc1
    |-it.mycompany.jaxb1
        |-Dev.java
        |-Ea.java


target/generated-sources/xjc2
    |-it.mycompany.jaxb2
        |-Dev.java
        |-Ea.java
```

Now I'm trying to unmarshall them in this way:

```
String schemaChhosed = "pathSchemaChoosed"
String packageNameChoosed = "packageNameChoosed"    

JAXBContext jc = null;  
Unmarshaller unmarshaller =null;

jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("packageNameChoosed");
unmarshaller=jc.createUnmarshaller();

Schema schema1 = sf.newSchema(new File("pathSchemaChoosed"));
Dev dev=(EdiL)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("myFile.xml"));
```

The trouble is that I'm not able to undestand what

> Dev

have to instantiate

```
it.mycompoany.jaxb1 Dev dev=(EdiL)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("myFile.xml"));
it.mycompoany.jaxb2 Dev dev=(EdiL)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("myFile.xml"));
```

I want to manage this in a dinamic way, can you give me any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to generate two packages out of one schema? This is what your config says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven-jaxb2-plugin VS jaxb2-maven-plugin for multiple schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543155/maven-jaxb2-plugin-vs-jaxb2-maven-plugin-for-multiple-schemas)